# How to setup secure blackberry email that uses PGP encryption?

Tags: blackberry, pgp

Im looking to setup private, secure email accounts. I'd like to use PGP encryption. What are my options for doing so?

Answer (score 2):

Although this is a fairly old post, but given that a lot of people search for this service, i am inclined to share some information. So to start with, You can use symantec PGP universal server (re-named encryption management server now) with your BES (Blackberry enterprise server) and Microsoft exchange. These can be setup on hosted servers (VPS) to cut down costs. You will need licenses for all of these. BES server license + user CALs + pgp support package, Exchange server + CALs and PGP Server licenses.

1. Set up AD and exchange on one server with good configuration of RAM.
2. Setup BES on second server. RAM requirement is lesser than Exchange. Configure IT policy under PGP tab to point to your PGP server.
3. Setup PGP on 3rd server and setup LDAP connection with the AD/Exchange server and use your domain name as trusted domain.

Activate blackberry devices and enroll with pgp server and download your keys and you are all set!! If you need more help, email me on baruah.samarjit@gmail.com.

Cheerz,
Sam

Answer (score 1):

You need to be setup with what's needed for PGP encrypted email first, then the PGP support package installed on the BlackBerry.  All of it is purchased and supported from PGP

http://na.blackberry.com/eng/ataglance/security/products/pgp.jsp

http://www.pgp.com/products/pgp_support_package_for_bb/index.html

You may want to consider using S/MIME since it's included with Outlook, etc and other then the cost of the certificates there is nothing extra to purchase.